# understanding 'this' and '$(this)' in jquery plugin

Tags: jquery

```
var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    var $this = this,$window = $(windw);
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            //if condition 
        } else {
            //else condition
        }
    });
};
```

In the above code I couldn't understand wh question about using 'this' and '$(this)'

Let see what I tried to understand by changing the code like this:

```
//var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
   // var $this = this,$window = $(windw); // as far as I understand $window becomes $(this)
    $(this).scroll(function(e){
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > pos) {
            //if condition
        } else {
            //else condition
        }
    });
};
```

I've also tried this much:

```
//var windw = this;
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
   // var $this = this,
      //  $window = $(windw);
    this.scroll(function(e){
        if (this.scrollTop() > pos) { // also tried $(this) here
            //if condition
        } else {
            //else condition
        }
    });
};
```

Oops! Both code doesn't work!

Can anyone please have better way to clear my concept on how the first placed code works?

Comment: In a plugin they'll be the same - the left-hand side of the plugin function call. If you do `$('.blah').followTo(…)`, inside `followTo()` the value of `this` will be the jQuery list that matched the selector `.blah`. Define "doesn't work". What does the JS debugger say?

Comment: but not working if I change to $(this)....

Comment: At everybody--- I know about this and $(this) but in my last tried code there I've placed this not $(this) but why it would not work. Any clear concept on my question code would be grateful to me.

Answer (score 0):

It will not work because `$(this)` will point to `your jquery selector` for which you created `plugin` not `window object`

And from your working code you want to `scroll` your `window` not `jquery your selector`.

If you try,

```
$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    $(window).scroll(function(e){// here scroll applied on window
        if ($(this).scrollTop() > pos) {// now this refers to window
            //if condition 
        } else {
            //else condition
        }
    });
};
```

Hopefully, above code will work.

Read [How to create basic plugin in jQuery](http://learn.jquery.com/plugins/basic-plugin-creation/)

Comment: So in my last tried code there I've set this but why it wouldn't work.

Answer (score 0):

within a plugin 'this' refer to selector on which u called a plugin & $(this) refer as jQuery object. Outside of any function / plugin this refer to window object. And in this plugin scroll function called on window scrolling to run some code. In your changed code, you will be refering some element that has no scroll event, so your code is not working.

Answer (score 0):

In JavaScript, ‘this’ normally refers to the object which ‘owns’ the method, but it depends on how a function is called.

If there’s no current object, ‘this’ refers to the global object. In a web browser, that’s ‘window’ — the top-level object which represents the document, location, history and a few other useful properties and methods.

When calling an object constructor or any of its methods, ‘this’ refers to the instance of the object — much like any class-based language:

in your code:

```
var windw = this; // there’s no current object, ‘this’ refers to the global object. ie, window.

$.fn.followTo = function ( pos ) {
    // now this referes to the scope instance of $.fn.followTo which is not window
    var $this = this,$window = $(windw);
    $window.scroll(function(e){
        // inside this closure this referes to the instace of this closure function which is not window
        if ($window.scrollTop() > pos) {
            //if condition 
        } else {
            //else condition
        }
    });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul class="swapify">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>

<ul class="swapify">
  <li>1</li>
  <li>2</li>
  <li>3</li>
</ul>
```

---

$.fn.greenify = function() {
    /** Here this refers to the JQuery object on which the plugin is applied,  It's got a prototype with all jQuery methods that can be inherited by your element (like css). As it is already a jQuery object, there's no need to double wrap it in $(). However, $(this) will also work but is not required. */

```
this.each(function(index, element){
   /** Here this is the same as element, it is a plain javascript dom object.  */
    console.log(this);
    console.log(element);
    /** Below line will cause error, because this means a plain javascript dom object hence it doesn't have css method. */
    //this.css("color","red"); 
      /** Below line will work well , since you have wrapped a jquery object. */
    $(this).css("color","red");
});
//  this.css( "color", "green" );
//console.log(this);// you will see a jQuery object in the console
};

$( "li" ).greenify();
```